# CMake конфигурация для библиотеки

Tags: cmake, makefile

Всем привет!

Есть задача,

1. Написать shared библиотеку (для windows .dll, дла Linux .so)
2. Заголовочные файлы библиотеки должны помещены в соответствующую папку. (для Linux /usr/local/include/{library_name}/*)
3. Должны быть возможность использовать заголовочные файлы в разрабатываемом приложении.

На данный момент у меня есть CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(PROJECT_VERSION "0.0.1")

project(mylib VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include(CMakeSources.cmake)
add_library(mylib SHARED ${MY_LIB_HEADERS} ${MY_LIB_SOURCES})

set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        SOVERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})

include(GNUInstallDirs)
set(MY_LIB_LIBRARY_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
set(MY_LIB_HEADERS_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/mylib)

INSTALL(TARGETS mylib
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${MY_LIB_LIBRARY_DESTINATION})

INSTALL(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${MY_LIB_HEADERS_DESTINATION}
        FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
```

Который выполняет почти все требования.
Возникает ошибка на пункте 3.

Например: у меня есть два заголовочных файла A.h и B.h, при этом B.h включается в себя A.h (#include "A.h").

После выполнения комманды make install, эти файлы перемещаются в

- /usr/local/include/mylib/A.h
- /usr/local/include/mylib/B.h

Теперь, когда я пытаюсь использовать B.h в другом проекте я получаю ошибку

/usr/local/include/mylib/B.h:1: fatal error: 'A.h' file not found #include "A.h"

Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему.

Comment: `/usr/local/mylib/B.h` — это же опечатка и имеется в виду `/usr/local/include/…`?

Comment: Да, вы правы, это опечатка, должно быть /usr/local/include/mylib/B.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одно из двух:

- Или использовать `#include <mylib/A.h>` в своих устанавливаемых хедерах.
- Или задавать `-I/usr/local/include/mylib/` при компиляции других проектов.

В первом случае, чтобы использовать те же хедеры при сборке нужно поддерживать соответствующую структуру проекта:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── mylib
│   ├── A.cpp
│   ├── A.h
│   ├── B.cpp
│   ├── B.h
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── CMakeSources.cmake
└── README
```

Примерное разбиение исходного `CMakeLists.txt` на два:

**./CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(PROJECT_VERSION "0.0.1")

project(mylib VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

set(MY_LIB_LIBRARY_DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}")
set(MY_LIB_HEADERS_DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/mylib")

add_subdirectory(mylib)
```

**./mylib/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
include(CMakeSources.cmake)
include_directories ("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

add_library(mylib SHARED ${MY_LIB_HEADERS} ${MY_LIB_SOURCES})

set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES
        VERSION "${PROJECT_VERSION}"
        SOVERSION "${PROJECT_VERSION}"
        PUBLIC_HEADER "${MY_LIB_HEADERS}")

install(TARGETS mylib
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "${MY_LIB_LIBRARY_DESTINATION}"
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${MY_LIB_HEADERS_DESTINATION}")
```

**./mylib/CMakeSources.txt**:

```
set(MY_LIB_HEADERS 
    A.h
    B.h
)
set(MY_LIB_SOURCES
    A.cpp
    B.cpp
)
```

Можно перемещать некоторые команды ниже/выше в силу своих эстетических предпочтений или потребностей.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста примеры CMakeLists.txt файлов для первого варианта.

Comment: @Luzifer, первый вариант предполагает внесение изменений в файлы с исходными текстами.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin В данный момент я могу себе это позволить, так как только начинаю писать библиотеку, на данный момент для меня самое важное чтобы `#include <mylib/A.h>` в коде самой библиотеке был доступен без необходимости выполнения make install.

Comment: @Luzifer, добавил

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо за пример, но к сожалению я получаю ошибку при выполнении make install, `fatal error: mylib/A.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Luzifer, скорей всего `${MY_LIB_HEADERS}` неверно наполняешь (из корневого каталога? glob'ом?)...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, `${MY_LIB_HEADERS}` берутся из `./mylib/CMakeSources.cmake`, там просто переменная со списком файлов. set(MY_LIB_HEADERS A.h B.h)

Comment: @Fat-Zer У меня получилось сделать это с помощью

`target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}> $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include>)`, спасибо всем за помощь.

Comment: @Luzifer, не сталкивался раньше с практикой выносить отдельно `CMakeSources.txt`... и ещё include'ы как-то странно устанавливались... поправил, как бы я сделал...